# How to "pop out" an IFRAME within my document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, userscripts

I am loading a page from the same domain into an `iframe` on my page.

After interacting with a JavaScript-driven form in the `iframe` I then want it to take over entire document. I can't just set my page's location to that of the `iframe` because there's no way to get it to the state I want it in by passing URL parameters.

All references I can find for jumping out of `iframe`s is about the page in the `iframe` controlling the popping out. I want to pop out the `iframe` from code which is in the context of the main document.

(My project is actually a Google Chrome user script interacting with a 3rd party site that I have no server control over.)

I'm using jQuery but vanilla JavaScript is also fine of course.

Comment: Why not just do a `location.href = "..."` in the main document?

Comment: `$("*").hide(); $("iframe").show().prop("target","_top")`

Comment: @sandradev: Because the page uses javascript forms. I can't get the page to the same state just by passing a URL.

Comment: @Imdad: This only caused everything in the page to be hidden `\-:`

Comment: Then you have to put 2 `div`s in <body> one will contain the iframe only and other div will contain all the other stuff. just hide the 2nd DIV. If this also does not work then post your HTML or jsfiddle of it.

Comment: I'm not sure I can transform it into a fiddle as it's a Google Chrome user script...

Comment: @Imdad: The `$("*").hide()` is hiding everything including the `<html>`, the `<body>`, etc - is that right?

Comment: yes, thats right. thats why I suggested to use 2 divs and hide 2nd div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't truly "pop out" of the iframe by the normal method (`location.href = "..."`), because you will lose your form and JS state.

Likewise, code like:

```
document.head=frames[0].document.head;
document.body=frames[0].document.body;
```

Would *appear* to work but would not preserve the JS state.

It may be possible to iterate over the frame's contents and copy structure *and values* to the current page, but this seems like a fool's errand to me.

I recommend that you just make it *look* like the frame has taken over.  You can do that with code like this:

```
var usurpingFrame = $("YOUR FRAME SELECTOR");
usurpingFrame.css ( {
    position:   "fixed",
    top:        "0",
    left:       "0",
    "z-index":  "8888",
    margin:     "0",
    height:     "100%",
    border:     "none"
} );
usurpingFrame.width ($(window).width() );
$("*").not (usurpingFrame).not (usurpingFrame.parents() ).hide ();
```

Comment: I was starting to think something like this might be what I wanted, but I lacked the specific know-how. I'll try this now thanks!