# how to pop out an iframe from document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, sandbox

I was included an iframe in my document now I would like to open it in a window using `"window.open"` without changing the context in iframe.

Is it possible to open existing iframe in a window without changing context?

Comment: What do you mean with 'without changing context'? Can you not grab the url that you have in the `iframe` and use that in your `window.open()` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "pop out" an IFRAME within my document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239205/how-to-pop-out-an-iframe-within-my-document)

Comment: @putvande I mean "javascript state"

Comment: @pauls I differs because I need to maintain state.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
 var w = window.open(null,'test',[800,600]);
 $(w.document.body).append($('iframe').contents().find('html'));
```

Basically just opening a new window with a title 'test' and a specific width and height and append the content from your iframe in to that new opened window.

You do need to have permission from that iframe (it needs to be on your own domain).

Comment: By doing this I lost js state!

Comment: Then what do you mean with js state? What are you changing or doing? Do you have an example?